# Javascript error in the chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently used the famous isotope plugin in my theme.
It all works fine on the page in which it is used, but in the other appears a problem with the console (I use chrome).

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope'

This is because all the pages are attached to the file custom.js where there is the call to the function isotope.
Can I solve this problem without having to edit the file custom.js eliminating the reference to the function and having to put it on every page in which it is used directly in the 'html?

Thanks a lot in advance to all

Comment: You can always conditionally call any method e.g. `if (obj.isotope) {obj.isotope(...);}` but why are you including code that uses isotope if you are not using isotope on those pages? Perhaps a little housekeeping of your js includes is in order?

Comment: Check your `<script>` tag which references custom.js is above the code which uses the `isotope` function.

Answer (score 1):

Be ABSOLUTELY sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file.